# Несколько манифестов для приложения

Tags: android, android-manifest

Может ли одно Android приложение иметь несколько манифестов? Например, один для стадии разработки, а другой для production.

Если да, то как это можно реализовать?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Можно. Читаем [доки](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/manifest-merge.html).

1. Создать папку **src/debug**. Туда дебажный манифест положить.
2. Создать папку **src/release**. Туда релизный положить.
3. В gradle скрипте прописать пути. Что-то вроде:

   ```
   buildTypes {
       debug {
           jniDebuggable true
           debuggable true
           manifest.srcFile['src/debug/AndroidManifest.xml']
       }
   ```